# SharePoint List Error: "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: sharepoint, list

Hi I am developing using the SharePoint namespace and I ran into the following error when I try to retrieve a URL column from one of my lsits.

```
 "Value does not fall within the expected range"
```

All I am doing is:

```
item["URL"]
```

Can someone tell me what I can do about this?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 8):

The error definitely means that the field can't be found.

Debug the process and look at the `ListItem.Fields.SchemaXML` property to find its internal name, it may be saved internally as something other than `URL`.  You can also use the following method to get a list item value.

```
SPField l_field = l_item.Fields.GetField("URL");
string l_fieldValue = l_item[l_field.Id].ToString();
```

The `GetField` method looks for a field by both DisplayName & InternalName.

Comment: I recommend SharePoint manager for looking at the schema xml and other fun stuff in SharePoint

Comment: Two points - don't forget about the SPBuiltInFieldId enumeration, and make sure if you're using the SPQuery version of GetItems that you include the fields you want in the <View> portion of the query

Comment: So why can't sharepoint just say "field not found" or something like that? maybe it's just me but these error messages are frustrating. it seems they are just letting the exceptions for their code bubble up and then let the programmer guess...

Comment: +1, @HenryC : I was missing the field in my `<ViewFields>` and got the error the OP had when I tried to use it.  Saved me!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To get the URL of an `SPListItem`, use `Item.Url`.

Comment: Not the URL I am looking for, I am looking for a column URL I created.

Comment: If it's a promoted InfoPath column, try deactivating and re-activating the form template to the site. I have noticed that I have to do this whenever I add a new promoted field to an infopath template.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static string GetItemURLValue(SPListItem item, string fieldName)
    {
        string exit = "";
        SPFieldUrlValue link = new SPFieldUrlValue(item[fieldName].ToString());
        exit = link.Url;
        return exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually means "URL" is not a field in the list.

If it's a promoted InfoPath column, try deactivating and re-activating the form template to the site. I have noticed that I have to do this whenever I add a new promoted field to an infopath template.

Comment: It might be null on the particular `item`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a special method for retrieving URLs. Try this:

```
SPListItem li = ...
SPFieldUrlValue fuv = new SPFieldUrlValue(li[strFieldName].ToString());
return fuv.Url;
```

Comment: Sorry, I see that ryan has posted a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is a Windows application. I used to get this exception after I created the set up and tried deploying.

My application needed to write in Excel and then save it. I used reference of COM component 'Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object'. I noticed when I add this reference actually 3 dll's appear in my reference list.

1. Microsoft.office.core
2. Excel
3. VBIDE

I removed the 'VBIDE' reference and my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a column name and in "Single line of Text" format, what about:

```
item["URL"] != null ? item["URL"].ToString() : "Not Found";
```